# formatting strings and text in a grid to look cohesive in C

Tags: c, string, formatting

I am trying to make my code print in a little more pretty way but I'm not sure how to fix my problem....

```
Protein:        Donations:0 Requests: 0
Dairy:  Donations:0 Requests: 0
Grains: Donations:0 Requests: 0
Vegetables:     Donations:0 Requests: 0
Fruits: Donations:0 Requests: 0
```

Here's the code I have for the print statement:

```
printf("%s:\tDonations:%d Requests: %d\n", TYPES[i], status[0][i], status[1][i]);
```

What I would like it to look like is this:

```
Protein:        Donations:0 Requests: 0
Dairy:          Donations:0 Requests: 0
Grains:         Donations:0 Requests: 0
Vegetables:     Donations:0 Requests: 0
Fruits:         Donations:0 Requests: 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to print the colon with the correct number of spaces after it. You can do this by taking advantage of several features that `printf` provides:

- `printf` returns the number of characters that it printed
- `printf` can left justify text in a minimum field width, e.g. in the format string `"%-10s"` the minus sign causes the text to be left justified, and the number `10` specifies a minimum field width of 10.
- the field width can be passed as a variable, e.g. `printf( "%-*s", 10, "hello" )` will print `"hello"` followed by 5 spaces

Putting it all together, the code would look like this:

```
int count = printf( "%s", TYPES[i] );
printf( "%-*s", 16-count, ":" );
printf( "Donations:%2d Requests:%2d\n", status[0][i], status[1][i] );
```